# Not able to access argument inside thread

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading, enterprise-architect

I have a function which i want to call it in a thread. The code is below. My problems is, when i override the init function i am able to access the argument(all types), but when the control goes to run, the argument is not accessible(only strnig argument is accessible other 2 are Colelction class and Repository class objects). The below code is a demo of what i am trying to achieve.

```
class ExportModel(threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self,Collection,repo,SelectedPackage,childLayerPackage):
        self.Collection = Collection
        self.repo = repo
        self.SelectedPackage = SelectedPackage
        self.childLayerPackage = childLayerPackage

        MessageBox(None, str(self.SelectedPackage), 'Window title',0)#Displays PackageName
        MessageBox(None, str(self.childLayerPackage), 'Window title',0)#Displays Child PackageName
        MessageBox(None, str(self.Collection.Name), 'Window title',0)#Displays Collection Name
        MessageBox(None, str(self.repo.Count), 'Window title',0)#Displays 10


        threading.Thread.__init__( self )

    def run(self):

        MessageBox(None, str(self.SelectedPackage), 'Window title',0)#Displays PackageName
        MessageBox(None, str(self.childLayerPackage), 'Window title',0)#Displays Child PackageName
        MessageBox(None, str(self.Collection.Name), 'Window title',0)#Doesnt popup a message box
        MessageBox(None, str(self.repo.Count), 'Window title',0)#Doesnt popup a message box

if __name__ == "__main__":

   ExportModel(Collection,m_Repository,"","").start()
```

Comment: do you have a traceback you can share?

Comment: there is no error nor any exception. hence i dont have any traceback :(

Comment: so then what do you mean "the argument is not accessible", was assuming you meant some type of `AttributeError`

Comment: i dunno if it is going for an exception or something. i also tried with try except, still no go. it just displays till the second messagebox, the 3rd and 4th dont popup. Is it because the type is unknown or the objects are created in the previous thread which is not accessible here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not joining the thread which is creating the message box. The main thread does not wait for the thread you spawn to finish, and program terminates before all the message boxes can popup. Try this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = ExportModel(Collection,m_Repository,"","")
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Comment: Nope that dint work. i think it is going for an exception or the object is going as null. not sure

Comment: where did you try to catch the exception? also there is no such thing as a null pointer in python!

Comment: it doesnt catch an exception, but whenever it encounters any line where i am trying to access that Collection class object member, it just comes out of the method.

Comment: Also the argument i am trying to access is a Collection class object of enterprise architect